# Why does gradle idea plugin configure classpath to use unprocessed/source test resources instead of filtered/generated resources

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to run my test cases in idea 12 after configuring my multi-project build with the gradle idea plugin. My project is configured to use the gradle defaults for test resources (src/test/resources). I apply some filtering to these resources:

```
// filter test resources
processTestResources {
    doLast {
        ant.replace(dir: sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir, replacefilterfile: testProps, includes: "**/*.xml,**/*.properties")
    }
}
```

Additionally processTestResources depends on a custom task that copies some "generated" files to sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir.

Many of my tests are failing, because they rely on the filtered test resources. When I look at the classpath that is being used for the test cases, it is pointing to rootProject/out/test/targetProject. When I look in there I see my test classes and my pre-filtered resources (and non of the resources that I explicitly copied over before processing the test resources). It appears they have simply been copied from src/test/resources. Is this expected behavior?
Also, why are the test classes and resources put into rootProject/out/rootProject as opposed the the defaults gradle defaults rootProject/targetProject/build/...?

Answer (score 1):

When you build in IDEA, Gradle isn't involved. It's IDEA that's copying the resources and compiling the code. You can add Gradle-generated resources to the IDEA build, but you have to run the corresponding Gradle tasks yourself, or configure IDEA run configurations to invoke the tasks. (I can't seem to find a post-compilation hook in IDEA.)